# Finding last snapmirror update date

Tags: powershell, netapp

I'm writing a script to check what is the last time a snapmirror relationship has been updated using PowerChell over cluster mode netapps.

I found that using snapmirror show on the CLI I could see "last transfer end timestamp" and there is also a property with the same name using PowerShell using:

```
get-ncsnapmirror | select lasttransferendtimestamp
```

Problem is at the CLI it shows a nice date (08/23 22:05:51) and using PowerShell all I get is a number (1471979101). Does anyone know how I could translate this number to a `DateTime` format? (`.ToDateTime()`  didn't work)

Answer (score 1):

It shows the total seconds from the beginning of `UNIX` time. So you could do:

```
$date = Get-Date -Year 1970 -Month 1 -Day 1 -Hour 00 -Minute 00 -Second 00
$date.AddSeconds($integer)
```

**EDIT** : After Ansgar Wiechers's comment.

```
$date = (Get-Date '1970-01-01').AddSeconds($integer)
```

Where `$integer` is the number you get. The result that I get is:

```
PS C:\> $date = (Get-Date '1970-01-01').AddSeconds(1471979101)
PS C:\> $date.GetDateTimeFormats('s')
2016-08-23T19:05:01
```

Comment: That's seems pretty close, but somehow I get a 5 hours difference between the two (19:05 and 22:05), I thought it might be a timezone problem but when I typed date at the netapp I got the same hour as my PC. Any ideas why? Or would you just recommend to add 05 to hours at the beginning?

Comment: @TomerSchweid That's probably a timezone offset. Try `$date.AddSeconds(1471979101).ToLocalTime()`.

Comment: @Syphirint Shorter: `(Get-Date '1970-01-01').AddSeconds($integer)`